# Por que no me da el style de mi elemento e.target?

Tags: javascript, html, css

No me lee la propiedad style de mi elemento cuando clickeo, solo si inserto el estilo en el html, si lo hago en el css no me va. Gracias

```js
//// MOUSE EVENTS =>
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; //selecciono todo el body para analizar
let resultado = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1]; //to print result

body.onclick = procesa;
function procesa(e){ // Por que se le pasa un valor???
  let ejeX   = e.screenX;
  let ejeY   = e.screenY;
  let nodeName = e.target.nodeName; //ver quien desencadeno el evento (e.target daria el objeto)
  let objetivo = e.target;
  let estilo = objetivo.style.width;
  let button = e.button; // left click(0), rigth click(2)=>
  let pulsar = '';
  switch (button) {
    case 0:
    pulsar = 'LEFT'
    break;
    case 2:
    pulsar = 'RIGHT'
    break;
    default:
  }
  let texto = '-You clicked in the ejeX: ' + ejeX + ' y ejeX: ' + ejeY + '<br>';
  texto += '-You clicked in the: ' + nodeName + ' which its object is ' + objetivo + '<br />';
  texto += '-You clicked in the: ' + pulsar + ' button with the value of: ' + button + '<br>'
  texto += '-The width of the element is: ' + estilo;
  resultado.innerHTML = texto;
}


////KEYBOARD EVENTS=>
```

```css
#section{
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>EVENTS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p></p>
    <section id="section">
      My section
    </section>
    <aside class="aside">
      ASIDE
    </aside>
    <footer>FOOTER
    </footer>
    <p id="result"></p>
    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qué propiedad es la que no te lee? La de `#section` ?

Comment: Si, bueno ninguna, quier oque me diga el width y no va, solo si pongo la etiqueta de estilos en html cosa que no quiero. Otra cosa, soy nuevo en esto, porque hay que pasarle como parametro e o event o lo que sea a la funcion?

Comment: el archivo style.css esta en el mismo directorio raiz que el archivo html?  si no te levanta los estilos deberias verificar la ruta del archivo style.css

Comment: si lo lee, ya ves que sale el border etc. leer lo lee, no tengo claro que pasa

Answer (score 4):

Efectivamente la propiedad `style` sólo tiene los valores de estilos definidos in-line en el atributo `style` del tag HTML. No incluye los definidos en tags `<style>` en el `<head>` o en archivos css externos.

Para obtener la definición completa de estilos del elemento deberías usar el método `getComputedStyle` del objeto `window`:

```js
//// MOUSE EVENTS =>
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; //selecciono todo el body para analizar
let resultado = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1]; //to print result

body.onclick = procesa;
function procesa(e){ // Por que se le pasa un valor???
  let ejeX   = e.screenX;
  let ejeY   = e.screenY;
  let nodeName = e.target.nodeName; //ver quien desencadeno el evento (e.target daria el objeto)
  let objetivo = e.target;
  let estilo = getComputedStyle(objetivo).width;
  let button = e.button; // left click(0), rigth click(2)=>
  let pulsar = '';
  switch (button) {
    case 0:
    pulsar = 'LEFT'
    break;
    case 2:
    pulsar = 'RIGHT'
    break;
    default:
  }
  let texto = '-You clicked in the ejeX: ' + ejeX + ' y ejeX: ' + ejeY + '<br>';
  texto += '-You clicked in the: ' + nodeName + ' which its object is ' + objetivo + '<br />';
  texto += '-You clicked in the: ' + pulsar + ' button with the value of: ' + button + '<br>'
  texto += '-The width of the element is: ' + estilo;
  resultado.innerHTML = texto;
}


////KEYBOARD EVENTS=>
```

```css
#section{
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
<section id="section">
  My section
</section>
<aside class="aside">
  ASIDE
</aside>
<footer>FOOTER
</footer>
<p id="result"></p>
```